# Can I use the TLC5940 LED Driver if I'm already using other SPI devices on my Arduino mega?

Tags: arduino-mega, led, spi

The way I understand SPI is that 3 wires are shared (MOSI, MISO, & SCHK). The slave select is pulled high when you want to write to a specific device. The 3 shared wires can be daisy chained. The TLC5940 LED Driver says that it uses SPI but I don't see any documentation about a slave select. Can I just include this in the standard daisy chaining and assign a new slave select? In some forums online some people seem to indicate you can't use the TLC5940 on the same SPI bus as other devices. I thought that was the whole point of SPI. Are there different forms of SPI? I'm quite confused, can I use the TLC5940 with other SPI devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I just include this in the standard daisy chaining and assign a new slave select?

SPI is normally used as a parallel bus and requires MISO to be tri-state (disconnected when not selected).

> In some forums online some people seem to indicate you can't use the TLC5940 on the same SPI bus as other devices.

The device does not have a chip select which gives a challenge. No direct wiring is possible but can be solved.

> Are there different forms of SPI? I'm quite confused, can I use the TLC5940 with other SPI devices?

It is possible to connect the [TLC5940](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc5940.pdf) but it requires some extra logic. You can for instance block the clock signal when it is not selected. This can be done with a MOSFET or [74HC125](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT125.pdf) and a pull-low resistor.

Cheers!